# Can't build Angular 4 example with Webpack

Tags: webpack, angular

I recently installed Angular 4 (RC2) and copied the files from the simple [Quickstart example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). But when I try to build the project with Webpack, I get errors stating that Rxjs can't be resolved:

```
WARNING in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
6857:19-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
6883:19-106 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular'
 @ ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 26:0-39
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

ERROR in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/observable/merge' in 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular'
 @ ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 23:0-46
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

ERROR in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/operator/share' in 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular'
 @ ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 24:0-44
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

ERROR in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/symbol/observable' in 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular'
 @ ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 25:0-54
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts

ERROR in ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'node_modules/@angular/core/@angular'
 @ ~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 22:0-45
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts
```

I've installed Rxjs 5.0.1, which I think is the version that Angular is expecting. I can't think of anything else to do.

Comment: did you run `npm install` before?

Comment: Yes, everything should be installed.

Comment: I thoughed you needed 5.1.1

Comment: I tried rxjs 5.0.1, 5.2.0, and 5.1.1, but it gives me the same result.

Comment: Having the same problem here...

Comment: I gave up on manually integrating Angular 4 and Webpack. Now I use Angular CLI to generate the project. Webpack loading is handled automatically.

Comment: some one resolve this issue?

Comment: is everyone issue resolved ?

Answer (score 7):

`new ContextReplacementPlugin(
  /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
)`

Works for me for webpack in webpack.common.js

Answer (score 0):

work with no problems under this configuration:

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
  /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
  helpers.root('../src'), 
  {} 
),
```

make sure on helpers.root have two dots, not one. ('../src')